# Adding element to every 15th position in an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an Array using List in C#. List data coming from a web service. I am using this array to create a table in PDF(spire.pdf). I want to add a header every 15th element. I can add the first one. From my method header value replaced an element in the array afterwords.

For example if I have 35 element in the list and I want to add the first row as the header row `rankListArray[i] = "No;" + "BRN;" + "Exp.Date;" + "Vehicle No;" + "Policy No;" + "Name of Insured;" + "Additional Covers;" + "Sum Insured;" + "NCB;" + "Amount Due";` to the array.

Then in the 15th position again I need to add this row. Then in the 30th position

```
    public class PrintedMotorRenewalCompactData
    {
        public string DUE_DATE { get; set; }
        public string CUST_NAME { get; set; }
        public string POLICY_NO { get; set; }
        public string VEHI_NO { get; set; }
        public double NCB_PERC { get; set; }
        public double SUM_INS { get; set; }
        public double PRM_AMT { get; set; }
        public string COVERS { get; set; }
        public int BRANCH { get; set; }
        public string BRANCH_NAME { get; set; }
        public string POL_STAT { get; set; }
    }


IList<PrintedMotorRenewalCompactData> rankList;

            for (int i = 0; i < rankList.Count; i++)
            {

                if ((i % 15) == 0) {

                    rankListArray[i] = "No;" + "BRN;" + "Exp.Date;" + "Vehicle No;" + "Policy No;" + "Name of Insured;" + "Additional Covers;" + "Sum Insured;" + "NCB;" + "Amount Due";

                    rankListArray[i + 1] =
                        (i + 1) + ";" +
                        rankList[i].BRANCH + ";" +
                        rankList[i].DUE_DATE + ";" +
                        rankList[i].VEHI_NO + ";" +
                        rankList[i].POLICY_NO + ";" +
                        rankList[i].CUST_NAME + ";" +
                        rankList[i].COVERS + ";" +
                        rankList[i].SUM_INS.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ";" +
                        rankList[i].NCB_PERC + ";" +
                        rankList[i].PRM_AMT.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                } else {

                    rankListArray[i + 1] =
                        (i + 1) + ";" +
                        rankList[i].BRANCH + ";" +
                        rankList[i].DUE_DATE + ";" +
                        rankList[i].VEHI_NO + ";" +
                        rankList[i].POLICY_NO + ";" +
                        rankList[i].CUST_NAME + ";" +
                        rankList[i].COVERS + ";" +
                        rankList[i].SUM_INS.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ";" +
                        rankList[i].NCB_PERC + ";" +
                        rankList[i].PRM_AMT.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                }


            }
```

Comment: "I am creating an Array using List" Is your `ranList` a `string[]` or a `List<string>`?

Comment: It's unclear to me what result you expect and what result you get now. I don't see the question

Comment: List<CustomObject> => List<String> with new element every 15th. Then call `ToArray()`. Inserting is the reason why you need a list. plus your string concatenation look like a CSV. You may want to use a CSV library to make sure you have the escaping

Comment: @ShamPooSham i wanna add this **rankListArray[i] = "No;" + "BRN;" + "Exp.Date;" + "Vehicle No;" + "Policy No;" + "Name of Insured;" + "Additional Covers;" + "Sum Insured;" + "NCB;" + "Amount Due";** every 15th position

Comment: Okay, and what is happening with the code you have now?

Comment: @DragandDrop . I am using spire.pdf library. It creates the table using **rankListArray**. no problem in creating the table. Problem is adding the header element row to every 15th position.

Comment: @ShamPooSham it will replace the 15th element in the array by the header element row.

Comment: `List<T>.Insert(Int32, T)` Method will insert at the index. then you can use simple math to find the index where you should indert the header simply by looking at the list lenght

Comment: How large is the rankList array?  If you have 150 entries and you add 10 more header rows you will have 165 entries and exceed the range of the array.  Better to use a list so you can add rows to the list.

Comment: I would have recommend making a [MRE] , imagine a List of 26 string representing the alphabet. You will add a custom header every 3 elements. Simplify your example you don't get disturb with the string concatenation. You will be able to write on paper the index for the header and deduce the math behind it.

Comment: You are writing to `rankListArray[i]` and `rankListArray[i+1]` - debug your application and check what rows you are really writing to. You may be going past the end of the list (with that `i+1`) and/or overwriting previous rows (with an i that is equal to a previous i+1).

Comment: Hmm, Reading your question again . You did not say anything about an header at index 0. You only talk about 15 and 30..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify you issue. I will assume that you are to produce a `List<string>` from your `List<customObject>`.

We start with a List with all letters of the alphabet. We will insert a header every 3 rows.

```
var header = "Hi, I'm Header!";
var headerRepeatsEvery = 3.0;  // .0 to avoid int division.
var inputs = Enumerable.Range((int)'A', 26).Select(x => ((char)x).ToString()).ToList();
```

Writing a part of exected result we have :

> Header!
>   1;A
>   2;B
>   3;C
>   Header!
>   4;D
>   5;E

The header are in index : `{0,4,8,12,16, .. etc}`
That look like : `X * 4`

Let's try to find how many of those header we will need :

```
List Size   |   Header Count
0               0
1               1
2               1
3               1
4               2
```

A simple division won't give use the result 4/3 = 1.3333.
We need to round it to the next int, and that's [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8)

Now the rest is simple for every Header index, we have to insert the header.

```
foreach (var index in headerIndexes)
{
    alpha.Insert(index, headerText);
}
```

Now we have our expected result we just need to make it a array : `ToArray()`.

[Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oz5Vac)

Your final code may look like this :

```
var csvLikeLines = rankList.Select((x, i) => $"{i + 1};{x.property1};{x.property2}"));
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0,(int)Math.Ceiling(csvLikeLines.Count()/ 15))
                        .Select(x => x * 16);

foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    csvLikeLines.Insert(index, headerTest);
}

rankListArray = csvLikeLines.ToArray();
```

---

I will recommend using something more rebust for concataining property value with `';'` semi colon. Soon enought one of the value will have a \n, \r,  or semi colon and everything will go boom.

As you are using it to create a report the strongest argument for using a mapper like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is that you will be able to arrange the column order, delete,  or rename one. Without going through the nightmareof remembering that column 7 is 'propertyFoo'. it will keep the header and the column easly maintanable.